# Promise loop that executes some things every time and some other things only once

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion, return, promise

I'm trying to do the following:

I have a function `looper()`, which calls itself based on a condition.

I want some parts inside of it to execute  only once, and some other parts to execute everytime it's called.

I don't know if this is the best approach but I couldn't come up with anything else and this isn't working.

```
var stopper = 3;

looper().then(function() {
    console.log('This should happen only once');
});

function looper(d) {
    if (!d)
        var d = when.defer();  // recycled promise

    console.log('This should happen EVERY time looper() is called');

    next();

    console.log('This shouldn’t happen if looper() is called again by next().');

    function next() {
        if (--stopper <= 0) {
            d.resolve();
        } else {
            looper(d)
            // if only next() could return a `return` 
            // so that looper() returns/exits based on this if condition ... 
            // return return
        }
    }

    return d.promise;
}
```

Is there a way I could achieve that?

Comment: You could pass an argument to it that indicates that it was called internally, similar to what you do with `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to undertand two things here:

- Promises/A+ recursively unwraps so you can return a composite promise from a handler.
- Promises chain. Rare are the cases you need a deferred object when already working with promises.

Once we understand these two things, we can create a much simpler "loop" since we can simply return a "composite looping" promise we chain via then:

```
// a recursive loop:
function looper(times){
    var p = when.try(function(){
         console.log('This should happen EVERY time looper() is called');
         console.log('This shouldn’t happen if looper() is called again by next().');
    });
    for(var i = 0;i < times; i++){
        p = p.then(function(){
             console.log('This should happen EVERY time looper() is called');
        });
    }
    return p;
};
```

In my humble opinion, this is much simpler than a recursive call that checks a boolean and an excess deferred object. It takes advantage of the strengths of promises rather than fall back into callbacks.

Now if you want a function that does something only the first time, you can do:

```
function initOnce(){
    if(!initOnce.wasCalled){ // functions are objects in JS
         // initial actions
         initOnce.wasCalled = true;
    }
    // other actions
}
```

Which works just as well with promises:

```
function initOnce(){
    var p = when.try();
    if(!initOnce.wasCalled){ // functions are objects in JS
         // initial actions
         p = p.then(initialHandler);
         initOnce.wasCalled = true;
    }
    // other actions
    p = p.then(otherActions);
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the best option but I would send a boolean variable from next set to true.

```
function looper(d, rerun) {
    if (!d)
        var d = when.defer();  // recycled promise

    console.log('This should happen EVERY time looper() is called');

    next();
    if(rerun){
        console.log('This shouldn’t happen if looper() is called again by next().');
    }
    function next() {
        if (--stopper <= 0) {
            d.resolve();
        } else {
            looper(d, true)
           // if only next() could return a `return` 
           // so that looper() returns/exits based on this if condition ... 
           // return return
        }
    }

    return d.promise;
}
```